# Stop the insert of element on drag over the dropzone in sortable jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have two question regarding jQuery UI sortable (two tables and a div in td which is moved between  tables)

1) I want to stop the whitespace from inserting when I drag over the dropzone. I tried the following but it does not work(also i need to highlight drop area):

```
$(".numdrag, .numdrop").sortable({
  placeholder: 'drophighlight',
  connectWith: ".numdrop",
  receive: function (event, ui) {
    if ($(this).find('.numdrag').size() == 2) {
      $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
    }
  },
  over: function (event, ui) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

2) I want to replace the data in the dropzone with the data that was dragged.

Comment: I just wonder, where did you get `receive` and `over` parameters to `sortable` method? Do you think, that you can simply add arbitrary options like `makeMeACofee`? You need to make considerable amount of modification to the `sortable` itself, to achieve what you want.

Comment: @user907860 the funny thing is that today, both those methods exist in the framework. They are events for a jquery ui `sortable`